# In which month is it impossible to become Bas Mitzva?

Tags: riddle, calendar, bar-bas-bat-mitzvah

In which month is it impossible to become Bas Mitzva?

Answer (score 3):

**It is impossible to become Bas Mitzva in Adar Rishon.** If a girl is born in a year where there is only 1 Adar then her Bas Mitzva in a year where there are 2 Adars would be in Adar Sheini. If a girl is born in Adar Rishon - 12 years later would always have only 1 Adar, **thus you can never have a Bas Mitzva in Adar Rishon.**

Comment: That last point isn't correct; it is most certainly possible to have leap years 13 years apart. Indeed, one of my own children was born in Adar I of the year 5763, and will be (bez"h) bar mitzvah in Adar I of 5776 - both of these are leap years. (Your answer would be correct if the question was about a *bas* mitzvah, because indeed it never happens that there are leap years twelve years apart.)

Comment: Oops, you are right. I actually did mean Bas Mitzva and am correcting it now

Answer (score 1):

Answer Here with extensive treatment of the topic in other Posts:

http://divreichaim.blogspot.com/2008/02/which-adar-is-real-adar.html

Comment: Good blog in General